# Bad SemaphoreSlim perfomance using a lot of semaphores

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, semaphore

When I run a lot of operations in parallel using `SemaphoreSlim` for each, their invocations are not so quick as expected.

Here is the code

```
  var sw = new Stopwatch();
  sw.Start();

  for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    int localI = i;
    Task.Run(async () => {
       var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
       await semaphore.WaitAsync();
       Thread.Sleep(1000);
       counter++;
       semaphore.Release();
       Debug.WriteLine($"{localI} - {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
     });
  }

  Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

And here is the output:

```
2 - 1015
0 - 1015
1 - 1015
3 - 2053
4 - 2053
5 - 2053
6 - 2120
7 - 3009
8 - 3064
9 - 3066
10 - 3068
11 - 3134
12 - 4011
13 - 4016
14 - 4070
15 - 4071
16 - 4073
17 - 4140
```

Can somebody explain why they were not invoked approximately in 1 second?

Comment: Add a Debug.WriteLine before you create the SemaphoreSlim and watch the results

Comment: BTW you do **not** see the SemaphoreSlim performance, but how the TaskScheduler is working (adding more WorkerThreads) ;o)

Comment: You are seeing how Thread.Sleep() gums up the threadpool with threads that are active but not making progress.  Consider `await Task.Delay(1000);`.  Unless the Sleep() is supposed to simulate real work being done, code burning ~9 billion instructions, then that's exactly what you want to avoid setting the machine on fire.

Comment: @HansPassant that worked, thanks! But number 50 is small for threads count I think. Could you please explain in details such behaviour? You can write as the answer

Comment: @SirRufo right, it starts not at zero second

Comment: 50 is only small when you have a machine with 50 processor cores.  Can be had, but isn't cheap.  Your machine has 4 of them, that's pretty standard.  So in effect it is simulating the execution of 4*9 = 36 billion instructions.  You are asking it to do 50*9 = 450 billion instructions.  That inevitably takes longer than a second.  Do keep in mind that this is an enormous amount of work, very low odds that Sleep(1000) is an accurate simulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is the limited thread pool injection rate. It has nothing to do with `SemaphoreSlim` or even `async`, as all the code posted is actually synchronous.

On your machine, three threads are able to run immediately. The thread pool sees that it has other work to do (47 other items already queued). So it waits for a bit and then injects another thread. The next group of work uses four threads. The thread pool is still "behind", so it waits for a bit and then injects another thread, etc.

The "wait for a bit" part of the description above is the limited thread pool injection rate. The thread pool has to wait for a bit, or else whenever it gets more work, it would immediately create a bunch of threads, which would then be disposed of when the work is done. So to be more efficient and prevent this "thread thrashing", the thread pool waits for a bit before creating new threads.